# Missing logging output in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have an issue with Python logging and I'm not sure what the problem is as the same line of code used to work just fine yesterday.

So for example the following code only produces output for the print function but not for logging.

Any ideas?

```
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
    logging.info("Hello, World!")
    print "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: `INFO:root:Hello, World!
Hello, World!` works for me, which python version

Comment: @avasal Version 2.7.3 and the strange thing is that it was working fine yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this alternative:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logging.info("Hello, World!")
INFO:root:Hello, World!
```

Here you are setting to the root logger the info level.

Comment: @Gabor: Setting it to DEBUG level should include anything on INFO level as well, so there is something additional going on here.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I think the problem is that logging.basicConfig is not configuring correctly the logger. From logging documentation "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it."

Comment: Right, so in the actual application, logging is already configured elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.info("Hello, World!")
INFO:root:Hello, World!
```

Also your code works in a file:

```
INFO:root:Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Comment: It works when I type in the code line by line onto the python interpreter, but it does not work when I try to run the file containing those statements